# Add way of viewing previous revisions while editing (Non editor user)

Tags: feature-request, edits, revisions-list

Currently, while editing an answer, there is no way to view (not change the current view, including loosing your working on changes to a revision) previous revisions (at least as far as I can tell).

Not sure how the community would think this best implemented?

At the very least, would be good to have a link to the question that one is editing, that could be opened in a new tab/window, to then be navigated to the edit page.